# How to set the query via JSON to an Elasticsearch SearchRequest?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

**Elasticsearch**: 6.1.2

I have an input query via JSON and would like to use the [high level Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.1/java-rest-high-search.html) to construct a search request using that query data.

```
String jsonQuery = "..."
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest()
SearchSourceBuilder builder = ?
searchRequest.source(builder);
```

I tried to construct the builder via:

```
SearchSourceBuilder.fromXContent(XContentType.JSON.xContent().createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, query));
```

but that yields:

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: namedObject is
>   not supported for this parser     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.NamedXContentRegistry.parseNamedObject(NamedXContentRegistry.java:129)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.namedObject(AbstractXContentParser.java:402)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.parseInnerQueryBuilder(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:313)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.parseXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:1003)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.fromXContent(SearchSourceBuilder.java:115)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm now generating the SearchSourceBuilder this way:

```
String query = "..."
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
SearchModule searchModule = new SearchModule(Settings.EMPTY, false, Collections.emptyList());
try (XContentParser parser = XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON).createParser(new NamedXContentRegistry(searchModule
            .getNamedXContents()), query)) {
    searchSourceBuilder.parseXContent(parser);
}
```

Comment: TFFY @Jotschi You just made my Friday.

Comment: @ndtreviv I'm no longer using this approach. Using plain JSON and REST is far more flexible.

Comment: Oh sure, if you want to refactor the world. It is, after all, Friday.

Comment: I see a lot of examples using `new NamedXContentRegistry(ClusterModule.getNamedXWriteables())` as the registry but it doesn't work for me. This works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same issue. We had been updating from ES 1.4.4 to ES 6.4.2 and I had used Java High Level Rest Client provided by ES to do create/update/delete operations in ES. I couldn't find an easy way to convert a query JSON used in prev ES version to an appropriate searchRequest using the High Level Rest Client. The below is what I ended up using.

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.Response;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Request;

public static Response executeGetRequest(RestHighLevelClient client,
            String api, String body) throws Exception {

            Request request = new Request("GET", api);
            if(body != null && !body.isEmpty()) {
                request.setJsonEntity(body);
            }            
            Response response = client.getLowLevelClient()
                    .performRequest(request);
            if (response == null) {
                throw new Exception(
                        "Get request have failed");
            }
            return response;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In createParser method replace the first parameter NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY with `JsonXContent.jsonXContent`

Comment: createParser only accepts NamedXContentRegistry - Your suggestion does not compile since the value is JsonXContent

Comment: Seems like it is available in v6.2 https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.2/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/json/JsonXContent.java

Comment: You can look at the test cases here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.2/server/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilderTests.java

Comment: That is an entirely different createParser method, from ESTestCase.