# how to search by custom JSON use Elasticsearch High Level Rest Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

[ES HighLevelRestClient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.3/index.html)

how to use `ES HighLevelRestClient` search by a custom JSON.

I have a query JSON like:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this JSON generated by mustache template [mustache java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) . cause I don't want to use `QueryBuilder`.

so I want to know how to search by custom JSON use HightLevelClient?

Comment: Why not using the [search template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search-template.html) directly?

Comment: my version is: `6.3.0` cause ES-version is 6.3.0, not support for that  /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~, or any problem if I use Client-Version `7.0` with ES-Version `6.3.0` ?

Comment: Even if that does not answer your question, your `bool` field should be wrapped in a `query` object.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48399046/3262646) ? It seems very similar to what you want to do.